# Procedure is compiled but when calling procedure and passing parameters I would receive error

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have created procedure for name change but when calling procedure I would receive error:
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 4, column 5:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PRODCHANGE_SP'
procedure:

```
    create or replace 
    PROCEDURE PRODCHANGE_SP 
    (
    P_PRODID IN bb_product.idproduct%TYPE 
    , P_NAME IN OUT bb_product.productname%TYPE
    ) AS 
    BEGIN
      UPDATE bb_product
      SET productname = p_name
      WHERE idproduct = p_prodid;
   COMMIT;
   END PRODCHANGE_SP;
```

BLOCK, calling procedure to check if is working:

```
 DECLARE
    lv_pname_txt  bb_product.productname%TYPE;
BEGIN
    prodchange_sp(1, 'CapressoBar Model #352', lv_pname_txt);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(lv_pname_txt);
END;
```

Comment: You are passing three parameters into a procedure that is declared to accept two.

Comment: I need to pass id and new name and get back new name that is changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fetch the old value before you update it. After update, overwrite the out variable with the old value.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE PRODCHANGE_SP 
(
    P_PRODID IN bb_product.idproduct%TYPE, 
    P_NAME IN OUT bb_product.productname%TYPE
) AS 
   P_NAME_old bb_product.productname%TYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT productname
      INTO P_NAME_old
      FROM bb_product
     WHERE idproduct = p_prodid;

      UPDATE bb_product
      SET productname = p_name
      WHERE idproduct = p_prodid;

    COMMIT;

    P_NAME := P_NAME_old;

END PRODCHANGE_SP;
```

You need to pass the value in the same variable as it is IN OUT. Rewrite the code to invoke procedure as below.

```
DECLARE
    lv_pname_txt  bb_product.productname%TYPE;
BEGIN
    lv_pname_txt := 'CapressoBar Model #352';
    prodchange_sp(1, lv_pname_txt);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(lv_pname_txt);
END;
```

Comment: Thank you @ArtBajji